# how to display progress bar?

Tags: delphi, progress-bar, delphi-7

I created a steganography(hide text in bitmap) application and I want to add a progress bar to show how long the process works.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   x,y,i,currentBit,bitInChar,currentChar,currentPixel,newPixelValue,pixelsToSkip,skippedPixels: integer;
   pixels: PByteArray;
   bmp: TBitmap;
   stringToHide: string;
begin
if Image1.Picture.Bitmap=nil then
showmessage('gambar belum dipilih')
else
   memo1.lines.clear;
   stringToHide := AntiKeyLoggerMemo1.text;

   stringToHide:= stringToHide + chr(terminator); // add terminator to indicate end of text
   Image2.Picture.Assign(Image1.Picture.Bitmap);
   bmp := Image2.Picture.Bitmap;
   x := 0;
   y := 0;
   pixels := bmp.ScanLine[y];

   // iterate over the chars in the string we want to hide
   for i := 1 to length(stringToHide) do
   begin
      currentChar := ord(stringToHide[i]);
      memo1.lines.append('');
      memo1.lines.append('Sembunyikan ' + stringToHide[i] + ' - Ascii ' + inttostr(currentChar) + ' (biner ' + toBinary(currentChar) + ')');
      // iterate over the bits in the current char
      for currentBit := 7 downto 0 do
      begin
         begin
            if (i = 1) and (currentBit = 7) then
               pixelsToSkip := 0
            else
               pixelsToSkip := 1;
         end;
         for skippedPixels := 1 to pixelsToSkip do
         begin
            inc(x);
            if x = bmp.width then
            begin
               x := 0;
               inc(y);
               if (y = bmp.height) and (i < length(stringToHide)) then raise Exception.create('gambar terlalu kecil');
               pixels := bmp.ScanLine[y];
            end;
         end;
         bitInChar := getBit(currentChar, currentBit);
         // get the value of the pixel at x,y
         currentPixel := pixels[x];
         // set the least significant bit of the pixel to the bit we read from the char
         newPixelValue := setBit(currentPixel, 0, bitInChar);
         pixels[x] := newPixelValue;
         memo1.lines.append('Bit karakter ' + inttostr(currentBit) + '=' + inttostr(bitInChar) +
            ', pixel ke ' + inttostr(x) + ',' + inttostr(y) + ' desimal ' + inttostr(currentPixel) + ' (biner ' + toBinary(currentPixel) + ') ' +
            ' desimal baru ' + inttostr(newPixelValue) + ' (biner ' + toBinary(newPixelValue) + ')');

            end;
         end;
   memo1.lines.append('All done!');
   Button4.Enabled :=True;
   Button2.Enabled:=False ;
   Button5.Enabled:=True;
   Button1.Enabled:=False;
   AntiKeyLoggerMemo1.ReadOnly:=True;
     end;
```

how do I make a progress bar for the process? and where I have to put the command progress bar?

Comment: @TLama: Well, but if this is run in the GUI thread, you have problems.

Comment: You need to move the calculation into a separate thread.

Comment: @Andreas, I've rather deleted my comment...

Answer (score 6):

First, you need to move the code to its own thread. Otherwise the GUI will not respond. You also have to make sure the code is thread-safe.

Anyhow, inside the thread, you need to update the progress bar every now and then. If it so happens that you have an outer loop and an inner loop, where the outer loop iterates once a second or so, you could update the progress bar at that place. If you only have one big loop, you might not want to update the progress bar at every iteration; for instance, a single iteration might perhaps be done in only a few milliseconds.

Instead, you can make sure to update the progress bar once every second, or so. To accomplish this, you can use `GetTickCount`:

```
tc := GetTickCount;
if Terminated then Exit;
if tc - oldtc > 1000 then
begin
  PostMessage(FProgressBarHandle, PBM_SETPOS, TheNewPosition, 0);
  oldtc := tc;
end;
```

This also shows a way to update the progress bar -- simply post it a message! You could also define your own message and send it to the main from.

Comment: where do I place the order?
do i have to create a new procedure or function?

Comment: I don't know what 'the order' is. But the code fragment above should be in the 'innermost loop' of your `TThread.Execute`. You have to learn how to use threads in order to do this properly, and that takes quite a lot of knowledge and effort. My answer only gives the main ideas and principles.

Comment: I am still a newbie so it was very confusing for me,,, but i will try it,,, thank you for helping.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, I guess "order" is meant as "command". At least both can be translated to one similar word in German.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand can you give me some example for use GetTickCount in a completed aplications.

Comment: @athogta: That wouldn't be meaningful. `GetTickCount` is a very simple function: it (basically) only returns the number of milliseconds since system start-up. And it works exactly the same in every possible application.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand yeah but i need an example to learn. because I've never use it before.

Comment: @athogta: There is absolutely nothing non-trivial about it. `GetTickCount`, declared in `Windows.pas` simply returns the number of milliseconds since the OS started, as a `cardinal`. So you can do `var c: cardinal; begin c := GetTickCount; ShowMessage(IntToStr(c)); end;` The function is part of the Windows API, and its documentation (which you hardly need for anything in this case) can be found [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx). You can create a new question at StackOverflow if you need more help.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand for the problem I mentioned above I had trouble determining the maximum value of the progress bar. what do you think?

Comment: @athogta: If you put the progress bar update in the outer loop, as in my other example, you have `for i := 1 to length(stringToHide) do` to worry about. Hence you can set `ProgressBar1.Min := 0`, `ProgressBar1.Max := length(stringToHide)`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I've tried it but did not succes. I think it would be easier if makes the memo as a parameter. when the pixel value is copied into a memo progress bar running. but I am confused how to write it into the program.