# how to display progress bar in delphi?

Tags: delphi, progress-bar, delphi-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to display progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790917/how-to-display-progress-bar)

I created a steganalisys application and I want to add a progress bar to show how long the process works.

```
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   q,x,y,leastSigBit,currentPixel,newPixelValue: integer;
   pixels: PByteArray;
   bmp: TBitmap;
  begin

   memo1.lines.clear;
   Image2.Picture.Assign(Image1.Picture.Bitmap);
   bmp := Image2.Picture.Bitmap;

   for y := 0 to bmp.Height-1 do
   begin
      pixels := bmp.ScanLine[y];
      for x := 0 to bmp.Width-1 do
      begin
         currentPixel := pixels[x];
         leastSigBit := getBit(currentPixel, 0);
         newPixelValue:=setBit(newPixelValue ,7,leastSigBit);
         newPixelValue:=setBit(newPixelValue ,6,leastSigBit);
         newPixelValue:=setBit(newPixelValue ,5,leastSigBit);
         newPixelValue:=setBit(newPixelValue ,4,leastSigBit);
         newPixelValue:=setBit(newPixelValue ,3,leastSigBit);
         newPixelValue:=setBit(newPixelValue ,2,leastSigBit);
         newPixelValue:=setBit(newPixelValue ,1,leastSigBit);
         newPixelValue:=setBit(newPixelValue ,0,leastSigBit);
        end;

         pixels[x] := newPixelValue;
         memo1.lines.append('pixel ke ' + inttostr(x) + ',' + inttostr(y) + ' desimal ' + inttostr(currentPixel) + ' (biner ' + toBinary(currentPixel) + ') ' +
         ' desimal baru ' + inttostr(newPixelValue) + ' (biner ' + toBinary(newPixelValue) + ')');
        end;
   end;
   memo1.lines.append('All done!');
   Button4.Enabled:=True;
   Button2.Enabled:=False;
   Button1.Enabled:=False;
   Button5.Enabled:=True;
        end;
```

how do I make a progress bar for the process? and where I have to put the command progress bar?

Comment: Actually, the answer to all questions of this kind is the one I gave in your [previous question today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790917/how-to-display-progress-bar). [If you *really* don't want to get into threading, you could just step the progress bar the naïve way in the outer loop and then do a dirty `ProgressBar1.Update` or `ProcessMessages`.]

Comment: @Andreas: A `ProgressBar1.Update;` works fine without the `ProcessMessages`.

Comment: @KenWhite: Yeah, I think so. But neither approach is good enough for software you are going to make public...

Comment: @Andreas: I agree. I was addressing your comment about the "naïve way" it could be done. :-)

Comment: @Andreas I am sorry but I do not understand how to do it.

Comment: OK, but what specifically don't you understand? Please don't keep asking the same question again and again. Are you wanting us to write the GUI of your app for you?

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do things like this is to do the computations in a background thread. Otherwise your GUI will freeze, and you might have trouble adding a `Abort` button. So you have to learn how to use threads (e.g., `TThread`) to do this properly. And your code must then be thread-safe, and you should only communicate between the thread code and the GUI in safe ways, e.g. using messages. The main ideas are found in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790917/how-to-display-progress-bar).

Anyhow, if you want to do this for educational purpouses or for private needs, perhaps the issues mentioned above aren't that severe. And then you can do simply like this:

```
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ...
begin

  ProgressBar1.Min := 0;
  ProgressBar1.Max := bmp.Height;
  ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
  ProgressBar1.Step := 1;

  for y := 0 to bmp.Height-1 do
  begin

    for x := 0 to bmp.Width-1 do
    begin
    end;

    ProgressBar1.StepIt;
    ProgressBar1.Update;

  end;

end;
```

To try this, create a new VCL project. Add a `TProgressBar` and a `TButton`. In the `OnClick` event of the button, add the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j: integer;
begin
  ProgressBar1.Min := 0;
  ProgressBar1.Max := 100;
  ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
  ProgressBar1.Step := 1;

  for i := 0 to 99 do
  begin

    for j := 0 to 200 do
    begin
      sleep(1);
    end;

    ProgressBar1.StepIt;
    ProgressBar1.Update;

  end;
end;
```

Be sure to notice the paramount backside of this approach, however. The application freezes during the entire 'computation'. You might not even be able to move the application window, and you will certainly not be able to interact with its GUI. Windows might even report the program as having freezed, and offer you the option to terminate it and send a bug report... Finally, since the entire GUI is down, there is no chance of adding a 'Stop computation' button. The solution? The dirty one is to use `ProcessMessages` and other filthy tricks. The proper one is to put the computation in its own thread, as already mentioned.

Comment: okay thank you so much it was very helpful,,I am just starting to learn delphi so need more examples of writing.